# How to extract `rawValue` from `Any` if value is `RawRepresentable`

Tags: swift, generics, reflection

I'm looking for something like:

```
func extractRawValue(fromPossibleRawRepresentable value: Any) -> Any? {
    return (value as? RawRepresentable)?.rawValue
}
```

I don't mind if extracted `RawValue` needs to be static type...

```
func extractRawValue<T: RawRepresentable, U>(fromPossibleRawRepresentable value: Any, expecting: U.Type) -> U? where T.RawValue == U {
    return (value as? T)?.rawValue
}
```

Context: I want to collect rather raw than actual values in mirror.

```
let d = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.reduce(into: [String: String](), {
    guard let label = $1.label else {
        return
    }
    $0[label] = extractRawValue(fromPossibleRawRepresentable: $1.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `RawRepresentable` has an `associatedtype`, so you can't assign `Any` to it. You also can't use it as a generic type because then you have to use the concrete type itself in the function signature, which defeats the purpose.

You can circumvent these problems fairly easily using:

```
protocol RawString {
    var rawValue: String { get }
}
```

This will allow you to extract the values using:

```
func extractRawValue(value: Any) -> String? {
    return (value as? RawString)?.rawValue
}
```

For any type from which you want to extract the `rawValue` as a `String`, just add to it conformance to `RawString`, e.g.

```
enum Foo: String, RawString {}

// or

struct StringContainer: RawString {
   var rawValue: String
}
```

The downsides to this approach is that you need to explicitly mark each type to conform to `RawString`, but unfortunately I can't see any other way.